# How can I trim "/" using shell scripting?

Tags: html, shell

I've been playing around with a little shell script to get some info out of a HTML page downloaded with lynx.

My problem is that I get this string: `<span class="val3">MPPTN: 0.9384</span></td>`

I can trim the first part of that using:

```
trimmed_info=`echo ${info/'<span class="val3">'/}`
```

And the string becomes: "MPPTN: 0.9384"

But how can I trim the last part? Seem like the "/" is messing up with the echo command... I tried:

```
echo ${finalt/'</span></td>'/};
```

Comment: quick question. Are you trying to extract out the number alone or the "MPPTN: 0.9384" ?

Comment: yes, sorry If I was not explicit enough.

Comment: No -- you were very clear. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of `${VARIABLE/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` depends on what shell you're using, and for bash what version. Under ksh, or under recent enough (I think ≥ 4.0) versions of bash, `${finalt/'</span></td>'/}` strips that substring as desired. Under older versions of bash, the quoting is rather quirky; you need to write `${finalt/<\/span><\/td>/}` (which still works in newer versions).

Since you're stripping a suffix, you can use the `${VARIABLE%PATTERN}` or `${VARIABLE%%PATTERN}` construct instead. Here, you're removing everything after the first `</`, i.e.  the longest suffix that matches the pattern `</*`. Similarly, you can strip the leading HTML tags with `${VARIABLE##PATTERN}`.

```
trimmed=${finalt%%</*}; trimmed=${trimmed##*>}
```

Added benefit: unlike `${…/…/…}`, which is specific to bash/ksh/zsh and works slightly differently in all three, `${…#…}` and `${…%…}` are fully portable. They don't do as much, but here they're sufficient.

Side note: although it didn't cause any problem in this particular instance, you should always put **double quotes around variable substitutions**, e.g.

```
echo "${finalt/'</span></td>'/}"
```

Otherwise the shell will expand wildcards and spaces in the result. The simple rule is that if you don't have a good reason to leave the double quotes out, you put them.

Comment: Very nice, simple and in plain english ;) Anyway, my bash is very old... is version 3.2 (can someone kill steve jobs? thanks)... And none of the `code`${finalt/<\/span><\/td>/}`code`is the only way to get the result... thank you for your explanation it was very good ;)

Comment: I've been testing other solutions posted here and this one seems to be the faster ;)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if using sed is ok -- one way to extract out the number could be something like ...

```
 echo '<span class="val3">MPPTN: 0.9384</span></td>' | sed 's/^[^:]*..//' | sed 's/<.*$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution largely depends on what *exactly* you want to do. If all your strings are going to be of the form `<span class="val3">XXXXX: X.XXXX</span></td>`, then the simplest solution is

```
echo $info | cut -c 20-32
```

If they're of the form `<span class="val3">variable length</span></td>`, then the simplest solution is

```
echo $info | sed 's/<span class="val3">//' | sed 's/<\/span><\/td>//'
```

If it's more general, you can use regexes like in Sai's answer.

Comment: I love this solution because it's simple and works on many contexts, it remind me C because it's easy to trim using the position ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the `sed` command for this kind of thing:

```
echo "$string" | sed "s/$regex/$replace/"
```